# Why does JS not follow typical sequential execution of code when using DOM API?

Tags: javascript, dom

JS sequentially executes code line-by-line. Check out this below example:

```
function tellMeWhatsPassed(thing){
   console.log(thing)
}

function createThing(){
   const div = {}
   div.innerHTML = 'original'
   tellMeWhatsPassed(div)
   div.innerHTML = 'updated'
   tellMeWhatsPassed(div)
}

createThing()

// {innerHTML: 'original'}
// {innerHTML: 'updated'}
```

EXPLANATION OF ORDER OF HOW CODE EXECUTES

To quickly walk through - JS takes the identifier `tellMeWhatsPassed` and bundles the code for further execution and moves to the next line.

It then does the same for `createThing`.

Once it reaches the call for createThing we begin executing that function. Inside of that execution context we create an object in local memory where we define an empty object and assign a key value pair: innerHTML and 'original', respectively.

We then call `tellMeWhatsPassed` with the object, `div` which is: `{innerHTML: 'original'}` , as the argument. `tellMeWhatsPassed` simply console logs the passed argument.

Then we return to `createThing` to continue execution and mutate the key which results in this object `{innerHTML: 'updated'}`

Then when `tellMeWhatsPassed` is called and given the above argument it simply console logs it.

Here we are going to update `createThing` to create a div HTML element instead of an object. The Thread of execution gets wonky.

```
function tellMeWhatsPassed(thing){
   console.log(thing)
}

function createThing(){
   const div = document.createElement('div')
   div.innerHTML = 'original'
   tellMeWhatsPassed(div)
   div.innerHTML = 'updated'
   tellMeWhatsPassed(div)
}

createThing()

// <div> updated </div>
// <div> updated </div>
```

I can't wrap my head around what's causing this behavior. What breaks the sequential execution?

Comment: It is sequential execution. But the DOM isn't rendered immediately when you change `innerHTML`, that only happens when the code returns to the main event loop. This allows JS to make many changes without the user seeing all the intermediate steps.

Comment: The sequential DOM updates (which aren't handled by JavaScript; that's the DOM API) are going to be completed one after the other in a very small amount of time. By the time the console code gets around to writing to the console, the second update is all it can see.

Comment: If you change your `console.log` to `console.log(thing.innerHTML);` (i.e. a primitive value, not a reference to the DOM element, which gets updated) you'll see the expected result